# How to match strings with additional part but not match them if they both have different additional parts using python

Tags: python, sql, mysql, regex

How to match strings with additional part but not match them if they both have different additional parts?
for example if I got a lists of names and need to match then with names in my Database:

```
|          My DataBase      |       Foreign table       |
| David James Malan Neeko   | David James Malan         |
| David James Malan Neeko   | David James Malan Mathew  |
| David James Malan Neeko   | David jam Mlan            |
```

I've tried to make a full match first if I didn't find, I would keep removing 1 character from the ending of the foreign name string and try to match again until I find it matching with only 1 record from my database.

This technique could match the 1st and the 3rd examples in the table above but the issue is it matched the 2nd example two since the program kept removing 1 char every time until the whole Mathew word was removed then it found a match which was wrong matching in this case.

Any recommendations what can I do to only match them on full match or on matching but only 1 side has additional section of the name, but not match them of they both have 2 different section of name.

Can use both SQL or python to fix this issue.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: It would help if you gave several examples of names that you expect would match, and several examples of names you expect  won't match.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix search in the second of the search conditions removes the need for a full table scan. Depending on your data, you can increase the length of the prefix, to improve efficiency.

```sql
SET @name_str = 'David James Malan Neeko';

SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(@name_str, '%')
OR (name LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(@name_str, 3), '%') AND @name_str LIKE CONCAT(name, '%'))
ORDER BY name = @name_str DESC, name LIKE CONCAT(@name_str, '%') DESC;
```

The first expression in the `ORDER BY` clause sorts the exact matches first, and then the second expression sorts the rows with the `name` starting with the entire search string before those where the search string starts with `name`.

Obviously, instead of using `SET @name_str = '...';` you just pass the search string in as a parameter.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SMOUXZfQ) with some examples.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a ton, you are the best

Appreciate it.

Comment: Is it this part  "OR @name_str LIKE CONCAT(name, '%')" that causes the inefficiency?

The table contains Millions of records. so I guess this won't work. will test it in 2 hours as soon as I'm at work.

Comment: Yes. I have added a prefix condition as part of that second search condition to remove the full table scan (updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SMOUXZfQ)). Adding more detail to your question will give some context, and possibly lead to a better solution. Are you searching on other criteria (date of birth, sex, country, etc) at the same time, or just the name? What is the structure (DDL) of your table and the foreign table? Are you loading data from the foreign table and then iterating over it, searching for each `name` individually?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the name only for the search process.

And yes, I'm uploading the names I received to another table and iterate over it for each name, then I try to match it for names in my database.

This is done by a COBOL program atm on IBM's Db2 for Z/OS but I wanted to make it better before I write the code once more in Python.

The issue is when I tried your solutions, I can't think of a single reason why is this happening but, when I query for a name as in select name from tbl where name like '(somecharacters)%' it works and it's an instant query

Comment: But when I tried the concatenation version that can actually be used within a program (i.e Select name from tbl where name like concat(name, '%') the query seems to take for ever, for the same name I just queried instantly a moment ago the only difference is I concatenated the '%' manually after written the name manually as well.

Comment: Maybe a typo in your comment, but `name like concat(name, '%')` will return all rows. Have you tested using the mysql cli before trying to get it to work in your COBOL program? My tests against a test dataset of ~5M rows returned consistently in <1ms. For your test case, how many rows are returned by the prefix search and how long does it take?

Comment: Unfortunately, My organization uses IBM Db2 and not mysql. I've tried to use db2 cli but still takes for ever when i use the concatenate method. Ver weird behavior. Can't think of a reason... It should be the same query

Comment: You didn't answer my questions about the prefix search. Maybe if you re-tag your question with db2, instead of mysql, someone will be able to help you.

Comment: My bad, and thanks you a ton for helping, I only added Python and mysql because those are the tools I'll implement the new application in, again sorry for confusion and thank you.